# Passing Firebase current user (as Future) as a parameter to a query in a Stream. Is it possible or is there another way?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a Stream building a list from a Firebase collection QuerySnapShot. The query and the stream builder work great, if I don't pass variable data to the query (the 'where' statement). However, what I am trying to do is pass the FirebaseAuth.currentUser as a filter in the where clause of my Stream.

I am sure there is something I am not understanding about making these 2 separate async calls.

Basically I need to get the uid of the currently authenticated user and pass that into the query in my stream.

I am super new to Flutter and am on a rapid fast track to get my chops. Been fully immersed for about a week.

```
class Booking {

  final DateTime startTime;
  final DateTime endTime;
  final String name;
  final String bookingId;
  final String truckID;

  Booking({ this.bookingId, this.truckID, this.startTime, this.endTime, this.name });
}
```

```
// build the booking list from the QuerySnapShot
  List<Booking> _bookingListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Booking(
          bookingId: doc.documentID ?? '',
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          startTime: doc.data['startTime'].toDate() ?? '',
          endTime: doc.data['endTime'].toDate() ?? '',
          truckID: doc.data['truckID']
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

```
//asynchronously get the uid of the currentuser from FirebaseAuth
  Future<String> inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser _aUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String _uid = _aUser.uid.toString();
    return _uid;
  }
```

Here is where I am trying to pass the current user into the Stream

```
  //get user specific booking stream
  Stream<List<Booking>> get bookings {
    final _myUserId = inputData();  
    return bookingCollection
        .where("truckID", isEqualTo: _myUserId) //Instance of 'Future<String>'...needs to be the uid of the current user.
        .snapshots()
        .map(_bookingListFromSnapshot);
      }
```

```
// the widget consuming the list
class _BookingListState extends State<BookingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bookings = Provider.of<List<Booking>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: bookings.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return BookingTile(booking: bookings[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT to include the Stream usage for feedback (after wrapping the Stream in a Future as suggested)**

In my home.dart file I listen for the `Stream<List<Booking>>>` so I can build the list of bookings that are displayed on that page. In this next block I now get an error that I cannot assign the parameter type `Stream<List<Booking>>` to the argument type `Future<Stream<List<Booking>>>`. The compiler suggests changing the parameter type or casting the argument to `<Stream<list<Booking>>`

The full compile message

```
lib/screens/home/home.dart:38:32: Error: The argument type 'Future<Stream<List<Booking>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<Booking>>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Booking' is from 'package:models/booking.dart' ('lib/models/booking.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Stream<List<Booking>>'.
      value: DatabaseService().bookings,
```

**home.dart**

```
return StreamProvider<List<Booking>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().bookings, 
      child: Scaffold( ... ) //Scaffold
      ); //StreamProvider.value
```

I have tried changing either the parameter `value` or the argument `DatabaseService().value` to the suggested types...and I have failed :)

**modified bookings getter after I changed it based on feedback**

```
  //get user specific booking stream
  Future<Stream<List<Booking>>> get bookings async {
    final _myUserId = await inputData();
    print(_myUserId);
    return bookingCollection
        .where("truckID", isEqualTo: _myUserId) //here is where I want to pass the currentUser
        .snapshots()
        .map(_bookingListFromSnapshot);
      }
```

Comment: Your function inputData() is asynchronous and returns a Future<String>.  This means you will have to `await` the result of it in order to get the string out of that Future, which you are not doing right now.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug. Does that mean that I need to somehow write that Stream into yet another `async` function (since an `await` expression can only used in an asynchronous function?

Comment: Probably.  I'm not really familiar with Dart, but in JavaScript, you can only await inside a function that's async.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use and await futures only inside async function. So first change your bookings getter as follows.

```
//get user specific booking stream
  Future<Stream<List<Booking>>> get bookings {
    final _myUserId = await inputData();  
    return bookingCollection
        .where("truckID", isEqualTo: _myUserId) //Instance of 'Future<String>'...needs to be the uid of the current user.
        .snapshots()
        .map(_bookingListFromSnapshot);
      }
```

So, where you are providing this stream, you need to provide Future then only you can get stream from Future.

Comment: gaining on it...one small change to your great suggestion; the getter also needs to be `async`

Comment: apparently now I need to either change the parameter 'value' type, or cast the argument `DatabaseService().bookings` to `Stream<List<Booking>>`

`return StreamProvider<List<Booking>>.value(
   value: DatabaseService().bookings,
   ....
  ); //StreamProvider.value
`

I am unclear on how to do that. Have tried a couple things that have not worked

Comment: thanks @dlohani  ... I have added both the modified getter (for posterity) and the Steam listener in which I am getting the latest error to my original post.